# TypeError: Cannot find function entries in object function Object()

Tags: java, htmlunit, htmlunit-driver

I'm using htmlunit to get this webpage

`https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies`

Maven dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
      <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
      <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
      <version>2.49.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm getting the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" ======= EXCEPTION START ========
EcmaError: lineNumber=[2] column=[0] lineSource=[<no source>] name=[TypeError] sourceName=[https://developer.mozilla.org/static/js/2.6b2c0865.chunk.js] message=[TypeError: Cannot find function entries in object function Object() {
    [native code]
}. (https://developer.mozilla.org/static/js/2.6b2c0865.chunk.js#2)]
com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptException: TypeError: Cannot find function entries in object function Object() {
    [native code]
}. (https://developer.mozilla.org/static/js/2.6b2c0865.chunk.js#2)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:949)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:650)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:540)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.callSecured(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:353)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:829)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:805)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:110)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadExternalJavaScriptFile(HtmlPage.java:1022)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.ScriptElementSupport.executeScriptIfNeeded(ScriptElementSupport.java:196)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeDeferredScriptsIfNeeded(HtmlPage.java:1474)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.initialize(HtmlPage.java:259)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:677)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:559)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:474)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:386)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:521)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:502)
        at rpvs.WebScraping.main(WebScraping.java:88)
Caused by: net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find function entries in object function Object() {
    [native code]
}. (https://developer.mozilla.org/static/js/2.6b2c0865.chunk.js#2)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:4396)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:4374)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:4407)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeErrorById(ScriptRuntime.java:4413)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFunctionError(ScriptRuntime.java:4520)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThisHelper(ScriptRuntime.java:2619)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThis(ScriptRuntime.java:2601)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1543)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:1013)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:111)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:430)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:339)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3665)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:123)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$2.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:820)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:934)
        ... 17 more
Enclosed exception:
net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.EcmaError: TypeError: Cannot find function entries in object function Object() {
    [native code]
}. (https://developer.mozilla.org/static/js/2.6b2c0865.chunk.js#2)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:4396)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.constructError(ScriptRuntime.java:4374)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeError(ScriptRuntime.java:4407)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.typeErrorById(ScriptRuntime.java:4413)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.notFunctionError(ScriptRuntime.java:4520)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThisHelper(ScriptRuntime.java:2619)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.getPropFunctionAndThis(ScriptRuntime.java:2601)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpretLoop(Interpreter.java:1543)
        at script.e(https://developer.mozilla.org/static/js/2.6b2c0865.chunk.js:2)
        at script(https://developer.mozilla.org/static/js/2.6b2c0865.chunk.js:2)
        at script.f(https://developer.mozilla.org/static/js/runtime-main.930f84d6.js:1)
        at script(https://developer.mozilla.org/static/js/main.e9dd68ce.chunk.js:1)
        at script.f(https://developer.mozilla.org/static/js/runtime-main.930f84d6.js:1)
        at script.r(https://developer.mozilla.org/static/js/runtime-main.930f84d6.js:1)
        at script.t(https://developer.mozilla.org/static/js/runtime-main.930f84d6.js:1)
        at script(https://developer.mozilla.org/static/js/main.e9dd68ce.chunk.js:1)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:1013)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.call(InterpretedFunction.java:111)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.doTopCall(ContextFactory.java:430)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.doTopCall(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:339)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ScriptRuntime.doTopCall(ScriptRuntime.java:3665)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.InterpretedFunction.exec(InterpretedFunction.java:123)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$2.doRun(JavaScriptEngine.java:820)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine$HtmlUnitContextAction.run(JavaScriptEngine.java:934)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.Context.call(Context.java:650)
        at net.sourceforge.htmlunit.corejs.javascript.ContextFactory.call(ContextFactory.java:540)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.HtmlUnitContextFactory.callSecured(HtmlUnitContextFactory.java:353)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:829)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:805)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.JavaScriptEngine.execute(JavaScriptEngine.java:110)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.loadExternalJavaScriptFile(HtmlPage.java:1022)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.ScriptElementSupport.executeScriptIfNeeded(ScriptElementSupport.java:196)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.executeDeferredScriptsIfNeeded(HtmlPage.java:1474)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage.initialize(HtmlPage.java:259)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:677)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseInto(WebClient.java:559)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:474)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:386)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:521)
        at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:502)
        at rpvs.WebScraping.main(WebScraping.java:88)
======= EXCEPTION END ========
```

This is my source code:

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;



public class WebScraping {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.BEST_SUPPORTED);

        webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);

        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies");

        String pageText = page.asNormalizedText();
        if(pageText != null){
            pageText = pageText.toLowerCase();

            System.out.println(pageText);
        }
      
        webClient.close();
    }

}
```

I don't know what is causing the error and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a problem with the current Rhino implementation. Luckily there is some progress on the Rhino development - the function you are missing seems to be on the way (https://github.com/mozilla/rhino/pull/902)

As soon as this has landed in Rhino i will update core-js and make a new snapshot available. Please check twitter (https://twitter.com/htmlunit) to get informed about updates.

Comment: thank you.  I don't get the error when I disable the javascript `webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);`. I'm also able to fetch the normalized text of the page, by doing so.